# Microsoft Excel, copying data using formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have two columns in excel, I have entered the values in column A, now I used the formula `A * 0.61` for column B. There are about `26000` values in column A. How can I enter all the values calculated using the formula for column B. Right now I am selecting a few values in B, and dragging them.

Answer (score 3):

Put your formula in first cell of column B and select the cell. After that put your mouse cursor on the little square in the right bottom corner of the cell so that the cursor gets a cross shape. If you double click here your formula will be copied down the B column as long as there are values in A column